# How to add textbox inside listview winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm working in Winform application.

I want to make a **listview with multiple columns**. In which the first column should contain string, the next column should contain textbox for input and output,the next column should contain button.

The main idea is the user should select the row with description,textbox,button. Once he selects the listview, he click on the button and a packet will be sended to device connected to ma com port and display the response in the textbox provided to that row in the listview.

It is possible to add multiple textboxes and buttons to all column.

Comment: did  you consider using datagridview?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your requirement is asking for `DataGridView`. Take a look at how to use the control on MSDN or any other place of your choice.